# Keep toolbox selection in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way in VS2010 to keep a tool selected after adding the control to the design surface (I'm using the WPF designer, but I think it happens with all design surfaces).

To be clear, this is an example of what I mean:

- Select **TextBox** tool
- Draw TextBox onto the design surface by dragging out a rectangle
- **Pointer** is now selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be simple. Hold the CTRL key down while drawing a control onto the page and the tool remains selected to draw another control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add multiple text boxes at once? If so, you can right-click the TextBox Tool in the Toolbox and select Copy and then Paste as much as you want into your Form, or whatever you are designing. If this isn't the functionality you are looking for please disregard my answer.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, and what I am doing at the moment, but I want to be able to draw the new TextBox in a specific location (e.g. a particular cell of a grid) rather than have it appear top left which is what happens with a paste.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is docking the tool box and dragging each text box you want individually.