# Missing VB6's shift-click adding of toolbox items in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, vb6

In VB6 selecting a tool to add to a form then holding down shift while you clicked the locations you wanted would add multiple copies of that item instead of requiring you to re-select the tool you wanted to add each time.  I miss nothing else about VB6 except that.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio behave like that?  When you're adding a string of radio buttons, or a collection of check boxes, it's a pain to have to reselect the tool itself repeatedly.

[Keep toolbox selection in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5553503/456188) asks a similar question, but I don't care if it's inherent in Visual Studio, or an add-on.  I'd even consider paying for such an add-on.  Copy and paste works, but is a pain and doesn't let you place it.

Comment: Hold down Ctrl instead of Shift while dropping, Escape to cancel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can add one, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down while selecting and dragging it to 'clone' it.

Just be aware that it will also copy the event handler bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Holding down `<Ctrl>` when you draw the object causes the control entry to stay selected for the next one. The last one drawn without `<Ctrl>` unselects the entry.